# How to tune Oracle SQL query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, performance, optimization

I want to ask whether it better to use Synonym or the actual name of the table to tune the performance of a SQL query?

Comment: Did you notice any difference? What did the query plan tell you?

Comment: I assume the difference would be in range of a few microseconds, or even nanoseconds.

Comment: @Wernfried Domscheit even it the data in the table is very large

Comment: @rene how to use query plan

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14211/ex_plan.htm#g42231

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A synonym is a label to an actual database object. They are used as a layer of abstraction.  The main use is for referencing objects in other schemas or remote databases. Using a synonym means we don't have to change out code when we move in different environments.

The performance hit of using a synonym is the look up. Given an object name in a query the optimizer will look for matching objects in this order:

1. a table or view in the referenced schema (default is current schema)
2. a private synonym in the referenced schema
3. a public synonym

So, if our current schema has a table `T23` the database will use that in our query rather than the table referenced by public synonym `T23`.

Depending on the state of the data dictionary the cost of this look up should range from utterly completely negligible to more-or-less negligible.

Using a synonym will not affect the performance of the actual query. That is, these two queries will have the same execution profile:

```
select * from synonym_of_some_table;
select * from other_user.some_table@remote_db;
```

> "even it the data in the table is very large" ?

Yes, even if the data in the table is very large. Using a synonym won't affect retrieving the data either way. Synonyms are not like views, which can make tuning a lot harder.